# Conflict in grammar YACC/Bison

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison, yacc

I have a YACC grammar for parsing expressions in C. These are some of it's fragments:

```
Expr: Expr COMMA Expr 
     | Assignment


Assignment: IDENTIFIER
            | Assignment COMMA Assignment

Function Call: IDENTIFIER PARENOPEN Expr PARENOPEN
```

What I basically want to be able to is to parse function calls of the form a(p,q,r) and check if the number and type of the the passed arguments matches that specified in the function definition such that they reduce to `Expr` at the level of identifier itself.

What ends up happening is that `p,q,r` are reduced to `Assignment` instead of `Expr COMMA Expr`. This is problematic since I need to run some semantic rules that can only be run using `Expr COMMA Expr`. Also it is not possible to remove the rule `Assignment COMMA Assignment` since it is critical for certain reductions. Is there any way that I can hardcode into YACC what needs to be done in such a case?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the grammar as written is ambiguous.  As you've noticed, when parsing an input `p,q` it can be parsed as `Expr COMMA Expr` where each `Expr` reduces from `Assignment` (which reduces from `IDENTIFIER`), or it can be parsed as `Assignment COMMA Assignment` which then reduces to a single `Expr`.

Which do you want?  If you ALWAYS want one or the other, just delete the one you never want as it can never come up.  If you sometimes want one and sometimes want the other, you need to say **HOW YOU KNOW WHICH** in any given case.  If it based on context, then you need to refactor you grammar differently so you can differentiate the contexts, probably by making `Expr` and `Assignment` completely independent.

In addition, you have the stand left-vs-right recursive ambiguity.  When you have `p,q,r` do you want it parsed as `(Expr , Expr) , Expr` or `Expr , (Expr , Expr)`?  Again you need to decide which you want under what conditions and set things up appropriately.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply Chris. I completely agree with you on the points you raised but the problem is I cannot implement either of the suggestions you made at the current stage. So, I would like to ask again, is there some back door in YACC by which I can explicitly state that when the said sequence of characters is seen, so and so rule must be performed?